# How to fetch the author profile picture on WebContent template?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-7.1

Can someone tell me how to fetch the web content author image in web content template? When I tried with the user object, it's returning the current logged in user and not the actual one.

I can fetch the author name and id by using the key

**<#assign authorId = .vars['reserved-article-author-id'].data>**

**<#assign authorName = .vars['reserved-article-author-name'].data>**

I have used the below code to fetch the content author image but it returns the current loggedin user.

**<#assign author-img = user.getPortraitURL(themeDisplay)>**

But it is returning the current logged in user image

I have also tried with the taglib

**<@liferay_ui["user-display"] userId="userId" />**, but its failing with a message "Failed to set JSP tag parameter "author" (declared type: boolean, actual value's type: String). See cause exception for the more specific cause...

Thanks

Comment: It'd be so much easier to explain what you did if you included your non-working code. And an answer would be so much more useful for others as well.

Comment: Hi, Here is what I am trying. I can fetch the author name by using the key reserved-article-author-name. I have used the below code to fetch the content author image but it returns the current loggedin user. <#assign author-img = user.getPortraitURL(themeDisplay)>
<img src="${author-img}" />
<#assign author-name = .vars['reserved-article-author-name'].data>
${ author-name}

Comment: I have also tried with <@liferay_ui["user-display"] 
    userId="userId"
/>, but its failing with a message "Failed to set JSP tag parameter "author" (declared type: boolean, actual value's type: String). See cause exception for the more specific cause...
"

Comment: please edit these comments into your question - they'll be a lot easier to read that way: There's proper formatting in that editor, as opposed to the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you about the solution from the top of my head, but here's what happens:

```
<#assign author-img = user.getPortraitURL(themeDisplay)>
```

uses the predefined variable `user`, e.g. the currently logged in user. Exactly what you get, but not what you want. `themeDisplay` is used to provide the current web context (e.g. host name that's being used) in, for proper URL generation that matches the currently displayed page.

Instead of using `reserved-article-author-name`, you want to use `reserved-article-author-id` to get hold of the user object with this id. You'll need UserLocalService for that (pardon my memory - I'm rarely using freemarker and would probably mess up how to actually do that, but you can search for that information. You might need access to the serviceLocator - which makes a good additional search term).

Having that user object (name it differently than `user`, e.g. `author`), you can get the author's portrait image URL with the same strategy as above:

```
<#assign author-img = author.getPortraitURL(themeDisplay)>
```

Comment: Hi Olaf, Thanks for the pointers. I tried the following                              
<#assign authoruserId = .vars['reserved-article-author-id'].data>
<#assign userLocalService = serviceLocator.findService('com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.UserLocalService') />
<#assign author_user = userLocalService.getUserById(authoruserId)/>
<#assign authimg = author_user.getPortraitURL(themeDisplay)/>
<img src="${authimg}" alt="Profile"/>

Comment: and getting this error : No compatible overloaded variation was found; can't convert (unwrap) the 1st argument to the desired Java type.
The FTL type of the argument values were: string (wrapper: f.t.SimpleScalar).
The matching overload was searched among these members:

Comment: Depends on the line that this message is being triggered on. It might be that the authoruserId is a String, and that's used as a Long in `getUserById` - You might need a conversation from String to Long before you can use it. Or it could be in another line - make these edits line by line in order to find the proper place.

Comment: Many thanks. I converted the string to number and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

This is working.

```
<#assign userLocalService = serviceLocator.findService('com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.UserLocalService') />
<#assign author_id = .vars['reserved-article-author-id'].data?number>
<#assign author_user = userLocalService.getUserById(author_id)/>
<#assign author_image = author_user.getPortraitURL(themeDisplay)/>
<img src="${author_image}"/>
```